# showing only a part of the object during an animation

Tags: animation, edit-mode

I am trying to model a moving wave and i want that the object should be seen during the animation only in a given region to give the desired effect. Could anyone help me out with it.

Below is a sample image from the animation (the wave should be seen only within the two walls even as it moves).

[image]

Comment: Presuming you're wanting to create a window between the two walls, this would be a simple matter in Blender.  Make either a Chroma-key aperture or an 'Inviso mask' to create an alpha layer hole around the window.  Only the area between the walls would be visible.  Is this what you're wanting to achieve?